# SwiftUI - How do I change a synchronous value using an asynchronous operation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an image of a padlock that must only show if a particular inapp purchase was not purchased, on SwiftUI.

Something like

```
  Image(systemName: "lock.circle.fill")
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(symbolFont)
    .opacity(wasPurchased(item: item))
```

But as far as I see `wasPurchased` must be a synchronous function, right?

Something like

```
func wasPurchased(item: item) -> Bool {
    return check(item:item) ? true : false
}
```

But, such checks normally happen asynchronously, over the network, and the function, as I see, must have a signature like

```
func wasPurchased(item: item, runOnFinishChecking:(Bool)->()) {
```

I don't see how I can use something asynchronous to control the opacity of such element.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use state property for that (or one in view model) and update that property.

Here is a demo based on state:

```
@State private var locked = true

...

  Image(systemName: "lock.circle.fill")
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(symbolFont)
    .opacity(self.locked ? 1 : 0)

    .onAppear {
       self.wasPurchased(self.item) { purchased in
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.locked = !purchased
          }
       }
    }
...
```

Comment: BRILLIANT, that solves for one case, but I am remembering that I have another case where the image is inside a cell in a list. Sorry, I am very new to SwiftUI. Do you need me to create another question?

Comment: One question - one answer ;)

Comment: [here we go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710021/swiftui-how-do-i-change-a-synchronous-value-using-an-asynchronous-operation-in)... 