# SwiftUI - How do I change a synchronous value using an asynchronous operation inside a List Cell

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709193/swiftui-how-do-i-change-a-synchronous-value-using-an-asynchronous-operation) previous question properly answer. That case is of an image somewhere in the interface.

I have another variation of the same problem but now the image is inside a List Cell.

That image shows a padlock that must only show if a particular inapp purchase was not purchased, on SwiftUI.

Something like

```
  Image(systemName: "lock.circle.fill")
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(symbolFont)
    .opacity(wasPurchased(item: item))
```

But as far as I see `wasPurchased` must be a synchronous function, right?

Something like

```
func wasPurchased(item: item) -> Bool {
    return check(item:item) ? true : false
}
```

But, such checks normally happen asynchronously, over the network, and the function, as I see, must have a signature like

```
func wasPurchased(item: item, runOnFinishChecking:(Bool)->()) {
```

That list is populated from Core Data, like this

```
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Expressao.getAllItemsRequest())
private var allItems: FetchedResults<Expressao>


var body: some View {
  List {
    ForEach(allItems, id: \.self) { item in
      HStack {
        Text(item.term)
          .font(fontItems)
          .foregroundColor(.white)

        Image(systemName: "lock.circle.fill")
          .renderingMode(.template)
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .font(symbolFont)
          .opacity(wasPurchased(item: item))
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

I don't see how I can use something asynchronous to control the opacity of such element when the whole thing is an array.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate your row content into standalone view and apply approach from previous post.

```
var body: some View {
  List {
    ForEach(allItems, id: \.self) {
       ExpressaoRowView(item: $0)
    }
  }
}

...

struct ExpressaoRowView: View {
   @ObservedObject var item: Expressao
   
   @State private var locked = true
   
   var body: some View {
      HStack {
        Text(item.term)
          .font(fontItems)
          .foregroundColor(.white)

        Image(systemName: "lock.circle.fill")
          .renderingMode(.template)
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .font(symbolFont)
          .opacity(self.locked ? 1 : 0)
      }
      .onAppear {
        self.wasPurchased(self.item) { purchased in
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.locked = !purchased
          }
       }
    }
   }
}
```

*Note: you can even keep `wasPurchased` checker somewhere outside (in parent or in some helper) and inject into `ExpressaoRowView` as a property*

Comment: I see it now! THANKS. This SwiftUI is new to me and my brain are still having difficulties wrapping around it. Specially after 20 years programming in other languages and 12 with  Objective-C, 5 with swift. Holy crap! Thanks